# Java version does not change in windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to change my java version because of  compiler errors when running `mvn install` via the windows command prompt. 
I changed the JAVA_HOME variable and made sure that it is referenced in the PATH variable (**##EDIT##**: had been done like this `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;`).

When I open the command prompt in the folder where my pom.exe is located (using the Windows 7 `'Open command window here'` shortcut) and type `java -version` the unchanged java version is displayed.

I made sure to close all instances of command prompts before starting a new one. 
Strangely I discovered that when starting the command prompt via the `Run dialog` in the `start menu` (by typing `cmd`) the result of `java -version` is the desired version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `'Open command window here'` shortcut make sure to **close and open the respective explorer window**. When starting the command prompt in this way Windows uses cached environment variables and does therefore not retrieve the current version of java.

---

Took me a while to figure out because it was too surprising to expect this behavior. Before I was searching on google and stackoverflow.com without any results. Hope this saves someone the trouble.

Answer (score 12):

I faced this issue too. I changed the JAVA_HOME in the environment variable and then when I opened cmd and typed `java -version`, I've seen older version. Then, I deleted javapath file in **C:/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java**. My issue has been fixed in this way.

Comment: The most straight forward answer. Fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You need to modify path variable as well as below:

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
```

Post that make sure you open a new command prompt and rerun maven command.

Comment: what if I want to change the version only in the windows command prompt?

Comment: @mannedear Then use SET command like `SET PATH=MY/PATH/TO/JDK:%PATH%`

Answer (score 2):

In my case worked the following: after editing the environment variables, and checking by command line **java -version** and **javac -version**, javac was updated but not java, so you have to do it by command line also
**set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing JRE setups..

Install the one that you need to install.
Hope you have added it in the environment variable and path via settings... Test it, it should work!.

The same thing happened to me long ago, It was pointing to the older JRE, got stuck, so removed the existing JDKs and installed a fresh copy. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem where I want to change the java version in command prompt but failed. But finally I succeeded doing the below steps. First I'll show the failed attempt, followed by the actual success step so you will know the difference.

Failed Step:
 1. Win + R
 2. Type `cmd` and hit enter
 3. Type `java -version` (Just to check if the version is the old one which we need to change)
 4. Now try changing the path/classpath using set path=/classpath=
 5. Now again type `java -version`(This will still show the old java version but not the new version which we set)

Success Step:
 1. Win + R
 2. Type `open command window here` and hit enter
 3. Type `java -version` (Just to check if the version is the old one which we need to change)
 4. Now try changing the path/classpath using set path=/classpath=
 5. Now again type `java -version` and voila I see the changed java version here

Thanks!